# How do i make a button in visual basic with a code?

Tags: vb.net

Every time I try to make a button with code, it doesn't show. What's wrong?

```
Dim NewButton As New Windows.Forms.Button
```

How do i make it show in Visual Basic 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button will not show unless you add it in the form.

Try this:

```
Me.Controls.Add(NewButton)
```

`Me` represents the current form where you are creating the button, you can replace it with the form name in which you want to put it.

Comment: Thanks! i wasn't expecting a answer that fast. :D

Comment: Kindly check this if it helped or answered your question. Cheers!